# Pressing in random locations: what does the blue circle do?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go, when you press on the map, you create a pulsating blue circle for a brief moment:

[image]

Does this have a purpose? Does it perhaps help you "look closer" at a particular spot on the map for potential Pokemon?

Comment: It just shows were you tapped.

Comment: @Dragonrage I know that, but I'm asking about the purpose of tapping :) ie why does it even show where you tapped?

Comment: Thanks @MageXy, I didn't find that when searching. This is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an indicator for where you pressed but also if you press again on the screen within 1 second of this indicator appearing you can zoom in and out by then dragging your finger up or down.